# Search keywords in ElasticSearch 7.6 with whitespace

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to implement in ElasticSearch 7.6 a search based on city names but I have a problem with those words containing whitespace as in the following example:

```
Query: "toronto, new mexico, paris, lisbona, new york, sedro-woolley".
```

This is my mapping schema:

```
mapping = {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "date": { 
                "type": "date" 
            },
            "description": { 
                "type": "text", 
                "fielddata": True 
            },
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my query:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match": { "description": escaped_keywords }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "pre_tags" : ["<match>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</match>"],
        "fields" : {
            "description" : {"number_of_fragments" : 0 }
        }
    }
}
```

`escaped_keywords` contains the previuos keywords escaped, as follows: `"toronto new\\ mexico paris lisbona new\\ york sedro\\-woolley"`

So, the query works for single name city and for those with dashes but not for name with space (new york, new mexico) which are splitted in (new, york, new, mexico).

I also tried to put the brackets for cities with space in this way `toronto (new mexico) paris lisbona (new york) sedro\\-woolley` but the result doesn't change.

**EDIT** Highlight doesn't work either with names containing dashes. It returns splitted words (eg. [sedro, wooley] instead of [sedro-wooley])

**EDIT 2** My intention is to match a list of dynamic keywords (eg. "new york", "toronto", "sedro-wooley") using **highlight tags**.
This is a sample of data:

```
{
    "_index": "test_stackoverflow",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "x4nKv3EBQE6DGGITWX-O",
    "_version": 1,
    "_seq_no": 0,
    "_primary_term": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "title": "Best places: New Mexico and Sedro-Woolley",
        "description": "This is an example text containing some cities like New York and Toronto. So, there are also Milton-Freewater and Las Vegas!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a [custom analyzer using char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) to remove the whitespace and hyphen (`-`) s**o that your generated tokens match your requirements.**

**Index def**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "char_filter": {
                "my_space_char_filter": {
                    "type": "mapping",
                    "mappings": [
                        "\\u0020=>",  -> whitespace
                        "\\u002D=>"   --> for hyphen(-)
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "splcharanalyzer": {
                    "char_filter": [
                        "my_space_char_filter"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" :{
        "properties" :{
            "title" :{
                "type" : "text",
                "analyzer" : "splcharanalyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Tokens generated by custom `splcharanalyzer`

```
POST myindex/_analyze

{
  "analyzer": "splcharanalyzer",
  "text": "toronto, new mexico, paris, lisbona, new york, sedro-woolley"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "toronto",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "newmexico",
            "start_offset": 9,
            "end_offset": 19,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "paris",
            "start_offset": 21,
            "end_offset": 26,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "lisbona",
            "start_offset": 28,
            "end_offset": 35,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "newyork",
            "start_offset": 37,
            "end_offset": 45,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "sedrowoolley",
            "start_offset": 47,
            "end_offset": 60,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

### Diff Search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : {
                "query" : "sedro-woolley"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "white",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "toronto, new mexico, paris, lisbona, new york, sedro-woolley"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Searching for `new` or `york` will not yield any result.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : {
                "query" : "york"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
 "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not work as I would like.
This is my settings ans mapping I used to test your solution: https://pastebin.com/KqniZe0N.
Highligh doesn't works with this solution.
I updated my question with a sample data

Comment: @bit, initially you didn't ask about highlighting , if you want to ask about highlighting ask another question and would be happy to help further, but its not community guideline to keep asking and modify the original question.